# Is it optimal to use multiple joins in update query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, subquery, left-join

My update query checks whether the column “Houses” is null in any of the rows in my source table by joining the id between the target & source table (check query one). The column Houses being null in this case indicates that the row has expired; thus, I need to expire the row id in my target table and set the expired date. The query works fine, but I was wondering if it can be improved; I'm new to SQL, so I don't know if using two joins is the best way to accomplish the result I want. My update query will later be used against millions of rows. No columns has been indexed yet.

Query:

```
(Query one)
Update t
set valid_date = GETDATE()
From Target T
JOIN SOURCE  S ON S.ID = T.ID
LEFT JOIN SOURCE S2 ON S2.Houses = t.Houses
WHERE S2.Houses is null
```

Target:

| ID | namn | middlename | Houses | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | demo | hello | 2 | null |
| 2 | demo2 | test | 4 | null |
| 3 | demo3 | test1 | 5 | null |

Source:

| ID | namn | middlename | Houses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | demo | hello | null |
| 3 | demo | world | null |

Expected output after running update query :

| ID | namn | middlename | Houses | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | demo | hello | 2 | 2022-12-06 |
| 2 | demo2 | test | 4 | null |
| 3 | demo3 | test1 | 5 | 2022-12-06 |

Comment: One performance issue with your code is whether it's possible for either JOIN to find multiple matching rows. If, for example, a source row had houses=2 and two target rows have houses=2, then you may start getting performance losses. But I'd expect them to be marginal. In terms of readability, however, expressing it using EXISTS() and NOT EXISTS () might make it clearer, and sometimes the optimiser can handle it better that way.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
update t
set valid_date = getdate()
from target t
where exists (select 1 from source s where s.id = t.id and s.houses is null)
```

Note that your original query does not exactly do what you want. It cannot distinguish source rows that do not exist from source rows that exist and whose `houses` column is `null`. In your example, it would update row `2`, which is not what you seem to want. You would need an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN`.

With `EXISTS`, you want an index on `source(id, houses)` so the subquery can execute efficiently against `target` rows. This index is probably worthwhile for the the `JOIN` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd need to join on the column `houses` at all.

Find all rows in `source` that have value NULL in the column `houses`.
Then update all rows in `target` that have the `ID`s of the source rows.

I prefer to write these kind of complex updates using CTEs. It looks more readable to me.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Target.ID
        ,Target.Date
    FROM
        Source
        INNER JOIN Target ON Target.ID = Source.ID
    WHERE Source.Houses IS NULL 

)
UPDATE CTE
SET Date = GETDATE();
```

To efficiently find rows in `source` that have value NULL in the column `houses` you should create an index, something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Houses ON Source
(
   Houses
);
```

I assume that `ID` is a primary key with a clustered unique index, so `ID` would be included in the `IX_Houses` index implicitly.